# Difference between escape('html') and escape('html_attr') in Twig

Tags: php, escaping, twig

Since version 1.9.0, [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) provides the `html_attr` strategy for the `escape` filter (see [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html)).

The `html` strategy uses the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) PHP function (this is confirmed by a quick look at the source). The `html_attr` strategy uses a series of custom substitutions that seem to have the same effect eventually.

Is there a difference between the two strategies?

Comment: I think that `html_attr` is safe for unquoted attrs, whereas `html` is safe for body text and in quoted attributes. I haven't been able to find a definitive cite for this, but I'd love to see one.

Answer (score 13):

The [source](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v1.9.0/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L959-L964) says:

```
/*
 * While HTML supports far more named entities, the lowest common denominator
 * has become HTML5's XML Serialisation which is restricted to the those named
 * entities that XML supports. Using HTML entities would result in this error:
 *     XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
 */
```

In practice, the `html` strategy only changes the characters that have a special meaning in HTML, while the `html_attr` strategy replaces nearly all non-alphanumeric characters, including spaces. See the example:

See this **text**, OK?

```
raw:       See this <b>text</b>, OK?
```

```
html:      See this &lt;b&gt;text&lt;/b&gt;, OK?
html_attr: See&#x20;this&#x20;&lt;b&gt;text&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;,&#x20;OK&#x3F;
```

In my understanding, for HTML, you can use the `html` strategy, for XML documents, you better use the `html_attr` strategy, but I have not tried this in practice.